# How to manipulate variables in deep class

Tags: java, class, parameters, nested-class

I just started to learn Java and i think this a very basic question but i didn't find the right answer yet so i try in here.

I just want to show in my console the names and descriptions of some animals, but i don't know how to manipulate variables from a class of a class.

I guess i have to use parameters but i don't find how to use them in a class...

My "Animal.java"

```
public class Animal {
    private String nom;
    public static String DESCRIPTION;

    public String toString(){
        return "Je suis " + this.nom;
    }

    public void direNom(){
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public void direDESCRIPTION(){
        System.out.println("Description: " + this.DESCRIPTION);
    }

    public String getNom(){
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom){
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    class Vertebre{
        int nbrVertebre;

        class Mammifere{

            class Ours{
                String nom = "Poumba";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Poumba";
            }

            class Chimpanze{
                String nom = "Cheeta";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Cheeta";
            }

            class Rats{
                String nom = "Ratata";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Ratata";
            }

        }

        class Poisson{

            class Requins{
                String nom = "Jaws";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Jaws";
            }

            class Raies{
                String nom = "Raimonta";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Raimonta";
            }

            class Truites{
                String nom = "Truita";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Truita";
            }

        }

        class Reptile{

            class Tortue{
                String nom = "Tortega";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Tortega";
            }

            class Serpent{
                String nom = "Serpento";
                String DESCRIPTION = "Description de Serpento";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My "TestZoo.java"

```
public class TestZoo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Animal unAnimal = new Animal();

        unAnimal.setNom("Jaws");
        unAnimal.direNom();
        unAnimal.direDESCRIPTION();


        unAnimal.setNom("Cheeta");
        unAnimal.direNom();
        unAnimal.direDESCRIPTION();


        unAnimal.setNom("Ham");
        unAnimal.direNom();
        unAnimal.direDESCRIPTION();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Also, look into _inner classes_. I don't believe you should be using them here.

Comment: You are using class nesting where it looks like you want to use inheritance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Ideone{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Ours poumba = new Ours();
        poumba.direNom();
    }
}

class Animal {
    protected String nom;

    public String toString(){
        return "Je suis " + this.nom + ", je suis un " + this.getClass();
    }

    public void direNom(){
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public String getNom(){
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom){
        this.nom = nom;
    }

}

class Vertebre extends Animal {
    int nbrVertebre;
}

class Mammifere extends Vertebre {}

class Ours extends Mammifere {
    public Ours(){
        this.setNom("Poumba");
    }
}
```